# Thymeleaf : не работает header/footer фрагменты

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Всем привет. Работаю с Spring boot mvc и Thymeleaf. Контроллер на "/" - фрагменты корректно отображаются
делаю контроллер на "/a{id}/b" который получает, например, "a3/b" и фрагменты перестают отображаться. Кто-то может подсказать в чем проблема?
или как задать тут

```
 <div data-th-replace="  /fragments/header  :: header-css"/>
```

эту часть в виде переменной? чтобы загрузить ее как стили из статика (что нить в таком духе бы

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-th-href="@{/myStyle.css}" />
```

Comment: Приведите пример кода.

Comment: Я разобрался с этим уже. Спасибо.